# Relay module not working

Tags: arduino-uno

I used 2 relay modules. One single channel 5 volt and  another 2 channel 5 volt. On connecting 5v of arduino uno the relay modules arent getting on(led on modules not on). 2 channel once worked with 9volt dc adapter supplying to arduino board.By work i mean the led on relay blinked as per code but no clicking sound.The next time i made the exact same connection and code it didn't work..Single channel arent working with 9v adapter also.Sometimes the led on single channel module is on but no switching and most of the times its not even getting on.i used 9 volt battery to supply vcc and ground to single channel module.This turned on the led on it but no switching.i don't understand how 9 volt powered 5 volt single channel relay without burning it.
Connection :: vcc to 5 v (arduino)   gnd to gnd on arduino
Digital pin 8 to in of module.
I used the blinking led type code and tried with and without serial.begin. Arduino is working as serial monitor was giving on /off output at every 2 second.
Load::200 watt bulb from 220 volts AC...under the limit of my modules i.e. 10A 230 volts
I tried 4 different single channel modules and 1 double channel.

Comment: And the Arduino is powered how? USB power is usually way too weak to switch the relay (poly fuse is fast and inrush peaks are higher than 500mA).

Comment: Provide a link for the actual modules used. Then maybe we can have an idea of how much current each relay requires to turn on.